# Sign Powershell file with Linux OpenSSL cert

Tags: linux, powershell

I generate PowerShell files using Linux PHP. Currently, I am signing them with this command:

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
        exec("openssl dgst -sha256 -sign \"$PrivateKey\" -out $file.signed $file > /dev/null");
}
```

However, this produces two files.
$file and $file.signed

I've imported the public certificate into the windows certificate manager, and have set PowerShell execution policy to "AllSigned" however I am unable to verify the powershell files.

When windows signs a powershell file, the signature is placed at the bottom of the powershell file.

How can I sign and verify these powershell files so that they can be verified in Windows?

Comment: Have you ever managed to do it?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro No, I never could verify the powershell files through the native verification that powershell has. I did find a project called Cleopatra for Windows that could do 3rd party verification. Using that, it is possible to construct your own script verification scheme - but I never bothered with it. Also, it might be possible to just append the signature to the bottom of the script - but no telling if that would work or not.